# Delete by mistake the storyboard

Tags: ios5

I delete the storyboard by mistake from my app.

Where I can find it and restore it,

or I lost it?

Comment: If anybody down vote anything on SOF, please give a comment. So that we can understand why. (This question was down voted before )

Answer (score 4):

The default storyboard filename is `Main.storyboard`, so that's what you should look for unless you gave it a different name.  (Older versions named it `MainStoryboard.storyboard`, so if you are working on an older project, you might need to look for that instead.)

First, check your project folder (using the Finder).  If it's there, you can drag it back into your project in Xcode, or you can use the “Add Files to …” menu option.

If it's not there, check the trash can.  If it's there, you can right-click it and choose “Put Back”, then follow the steps in the previous paragraph.

Comment: The name was MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard. I check my project with Finder but nothing.I Also check my trash but there wasn't. Any ideas where the Xcode sent the deleted files?

Comment: The only solution I found is the following link (but not totally solution) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/SCM/SCM.html

Comment: I found it in the trash and did "Put Back". Now I am unable to find the storyboard in the trash and neither in my xcode project

Comment: If you told Xcode to delete the storyboard, then “Put Back” puts the file back in your project folder (on disk), but doesn't update the Xcode project file to know about it again.  You can add it back to your Xcode project by choosing Add Files to “MyProject” from the File menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try running again your app and Xcode will create the file automatically, this worked for me.